# MySQL populate another table - Using Procedure or another way

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, sql-insert

i have a two tables on my database .

a table called 'a' that have this structure :

```
ID  COD     F   L   Q S
1   MI001   1   1   1 E
2   MI002   1   1   1 E
3   MI003   2   2   2 E
4   MI004   1   2   3 E
5   MI005   1   1   1 E
```

a table called 'b' that i have this structure

```
ID | A_ID | A_ID_NEW
```

what i wanna is , imagine that a i have a button or function on my application that i catch the ids from table 'a' for example , i catch ids '1' and '2' .

so i'll insert on table a , a new register geting data from your id , so table 'a' must be like below :

```
ID  COD     F   L   Q S
1   MI001   1   1   1 E
2   MI002   1   2   1 E
3   MI003   2   2   2 E
4   MI004   1   2   3 E
5   MI005   1   1   1 E
6   MI001   1   1   1 T
7   MI002   1   2   1 T
```

and insert on table called 'b' like this below :

```
ID | A_ID | A_ID_NEW
1  | 1    | 6
2  | 2    | 7
```

its possible ?

Comment: Why new IDs in table `b` are 4 and 5 whereas in table `a` they are 6 and 7? Does the column `S` is strictly `'E'` and in a row copy it must be set strictly to `'T'`? *its possible ?* Of course. One query + one trigger. Or 2 queries in transaction.

Comment: sorry , i have edit . the column S could have another status , but when the user click on transfer ( my back-end app ) he must be 'T' .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE populate_rows (ids TEXT)
BEGIN
DECLARE id INT;
DECLARE cod CHAR(5);
DECLARE f TINYINT;
DECLARE l TINYINT;
DECLARE q TINYINT;
DECLARE s CHAR(1);
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM a WHERE FIND_IN_SET(a.id, ids);
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
OPEN cur;
cycle: REPEAT
    FETCH cur INTO id, cod, f, l, q, s;
    IF done THEN
        LEAVE cycle;
    END IF;
    INSERT INTO a VALUES (NULL, cod, f, l, q, 'T');
    INSERT INTO b SELECT NULL, id, MAX(a.id) FROM a;
UNTIL done END REPEAT cycle;
END
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=29669e36588af9519d710b57f6b76c5d)

PS. The procedure does not take into account any interference from parallel processes or any other problems that may occur during the process.

PPS. Adjust datatypes of local variables according to your actual table structure.